# Update values using joins and where

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I've tried the following commands:

```
UPDATE staff SET salary = (salary * 1.1)
where branchno = (select branchno from branch where city = 'London');

update salary from staff s join branch b on s.branchno = b.branchno
where b.city = 'London' set salary = salary * 1.1;
```

However, I get this back as an error:

```
> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Any ideas? essentially I want to update all members of staff's salaries by 10% that live in London, but I must join the Staff and Branch table to get the branches location.

Comment: You want a join - see `UPDATE ... FROM ...`

Comment: I tried this last time but can't get past the from =/ : update salary from staff s join branch b on s.branchno = b.branchno where b.city = 'London' set salary = salary * 1.1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query transformed to proper join syntax:

```
UPDATE staff s
SET    salary = (salary * 1.1)
FROM   branch b
WHERE  b.city = 'London'
AND    s.branchno = b.branchno;
```

This avoids the reported error. [The manual has more on `UPDATE`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)

Comment: Thank you! Makes much sense XD